# c++ undefined reference to function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a generic Queue class.
The Template class looks like it:
Queue.h

```
template <class T>
class Queue {
public:
  Queue() {}
 ~Queue() {} 

...

  void enqueue( const T& e );
  T dequeue( void );

  int Size( void ) const { return s1.size() + s2.size();}    

private:
    std::stack<T> s1;
    std::stack<T> s2;
};

#include "Queue.cpp"
```

And the implementation of it looks like it:
Queue.cpp:

```
#include "Queue.h"

template <class T>
void Queue<T>::enqueue( const T& e )
{
//...
}

template <class T>
T Queue<T>::dequeue ()
{
//...
}
```

my Problem is, i can't call some function of this class whtich I've implemented in the file Queue.cpp.

main.cpp:

```
int main() {
Queue<int> myQueue;

const int a = 1;
 myQueue.enqueue(a);

 myQueue.Size();

return 0;
}
```

i become always the follwing erro:
undefined reference to Queue::enqueue(int const&)

[Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Makefile.winrecipe for target 'MYQueue.exe' failed

Comment: I includee accordings to this post, the implementation file at the end of the header. And now I become the errors: [Error] redefinition of 'Queue<T>::Queue(const Queue<T>&)' etc...

Answer (score 1):

Place the whole template definition including its member functions in one header file.

Comment: Alternative: Explicitly instantiate the template with the proper template arguments in the .cpp file.

Comment: @Deduplicator You are right.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I don't understand, could you maybe show it?